# Javascript iterator design pattern

Tags: javascript

I am confused why the following code snippet has `(i)` at the end of it:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
  (function(i) { 
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(i);
    }, 1000);
  })(i);
}
```

Ive seen it in production code Ive worked on--I just can intuit why it's necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining an inline function, so you could force the `i` parameter to be in the local scope at the time of the execution of the `console.log` statement. By adding the parameter, you are creating a self executing function. Similar would be the following statements, which might be better to read...

```
function logmeWithTimeOut(value) {
    setTimeout(function() { console.log(value); }, 1000);
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    logmeWithTimeout(i);
}
```

Though I might prefer

```
function logmeWithTimeout(value) {
     console.log(value);
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(logmeWithTimeout.bind(undefined, i), 1000);
}
```

It forces the i to be in local scope, otherwise your log would print only 11

Comment: your use of 'it' is quite ambiguous here

Comment: @redress, sorry, i clarified the it in my post :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you are defining a function inside the parenthesis, and then you are calling it passing `i` as parameter.

If you didn't put the `(i)` there, you would just define a function but never call it.